# Zend Filter Encryption / Decryption adds nullbytes when decrypting

Tags: zend-framework, encryption, filter, padding

I am trying to do some symmetric encryption on some data with the Zend_Filter_Encrypt function. The problem is if i encrypt some data and then later decrypt it, there are nullbytes behind the decrypted data and I have no idea why.

For instance:
Plaintext: test Encrypted: ����pk� Decrypted: test����

It seems to be padding nullbytes at the end of the decrypted text to make it's length equal to some 2^n (a string with 11 characters is padded to fit 16 => 2^4). The most obvious thing would be to just strip these characters but I want to know why this is happening...

This is the code I'm using, which is different than how the documentation wants you to do it because their code just doesn't work for me (see: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html)

```
    define('VECTOR','EXfPCW23'); //example, not the actual used VECTOR / KEY
    $key = 'lolwatlolwat';

    public function encryptPassword($password, $key)
    {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_Encrypt();
            $filter->setEncryption(array('key' => $key));       
            $filter->setVector(VECTOR);

            return $filter->filter($password);      
    }

    public function decryptPassword($password, $key)
    {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_Decrypt();
            $filter->setEncryption(array('key' => $key));
            $filter->setVector(VECTOR);

            return $filter->filter($password);
    }
```

Comment: Hm I just realised that 'test' is 4 characters which is 2^2 so now I don't understand it at all ._.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **rtrim** function on Decrypt string.

Example:

```
   public function decryptPassword($password, $key)
    {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_Decrypt();
            $filter->setEncryption(array('key' => $key));
            $filter->setVector(VECTOR);

            return rtrim($filter->filter($password);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the Zend documentation tell you how to specify the padding?  If so then specify a reversible padding; as you have found, zero padding is not reversible.  Otherwise, find out what size padded plaintext Zend is expecting and add PKCS7 padding yourself.  This is easily recognisable and removable afterwards.